# Adding different animated widget at same map in cartobuilder

Tags: carto, widget

I have 4 layers in Carto and I want to make animated maps for each of them but it seems I can only make one.

Is there any way that I can make more than one?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Thank you for having taken our short [tour] to learn about how the site works.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it cannot be added more than one animated layer to a Builder map. I was not able to find any reference in order to certify this limitation on the current CARTO documentation. On the other hand, f you want to animate more than one layer using CARTO technology, you could do it programatically using [CARTO VL library](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/).

Comment: Good Morning Ramiro,

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If you think the answer solved your question, please mark it.